# ++i and i++ in while loop in C

Tags: c, loops, gcc, while-loop

I am using a program to detect the boundary of each data type, which is like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    /*first while loop using a++ dosesn't give us a right answer*/
    int a = 0;
    while (a++ > 0);
        printf("int max first = %d\n", a-1);

    /*second while loop using ++a performs well*/
    int b = 0;
    while (++b > 0);
        printf("int max second = %d\n", b-1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

After I compile this propram and excute it, it returns:

```
int max first = 0
int max second = 2147483647
```

So I try to debug it, and I find out that in the first part, after `a++` becomes `1`, then it just stop autoincrement and jump the `while` loop，while in second part it runs well, why is this happening?

Comment: Note that signed integer arithmetic overflow (which you get in your loop conditions) leads to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: I know that, that is what I am trying to do, using this oveflow condition to get the max  number an 'int' type can express.@Some programmer dude

Comment: But [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) means you're doing something *wrong*. If your program have undefined behavior, then it's invalid.

Comment: You cannot extract **any** meaningful information from a program with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Just because noone mentioned it yet... are you aware of macros like  `INT_MAX`? They are exactly present for this purpose.

Comment: Compile with optimizations enabled on recent GCC for x86 and it prints `int max first = 0` and then hangs.

Comment: ok，I don't know why all of your program encounter situations like `undefined behavior`, in my computer, with vc++ compiler or minGW32, it works fine and no warning happend, anybody know why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pre-increment operator (e.g. `++b`) is done *first*, and the value of the expression is the incremented value.

That is

```
int b = 0;
while (++b > 0) ...
```

will increment `b` *first* and then check its value using the larger-than comparison. Since in the very first iteration `++b` will make `b` equal to `1` the condition will be `1 > 0` which is true.

Now the *post*-increment operator does the increment *after* the *old* value is used.

So for example `a++` will return the *old* value of `a` and *then* do the increment.

So with

```
int a = 0;
while (a++ > 0) ...
```

the very first iteration `a++` will return `0` which means you have the condition `0 > 0` which is *false* and the loop will never even iterate once. But the value of `a` will still be incremented, so afterwards it will be equal to `1` (when the loop have already ended).

This behavior of the pre- and post-operators should be part of any decent book, tutorial or class.

Answer (score 2):

> after a++ becomes 1, then it just stop autoincrement and jump the
>   while loop

This happens because of the post and pre increment operators and the `;` in `while` loop working together.

`a` will be incremented by `1` *after* the condition `a++ > 0` is evaluated. Thus, the condition fails. The `;` at the end of the `while` statement results in an empty loop and the next print statement will be executed even if the condition on which the `while` loop is based returns true.

This is exactly what happens in the second `while` loop - the pre increment operator will increment `b` before the condition is checked inside `while (++b > 0);`. The empty `while` loop keeps on adding one to the value of `b` until there is an overflow.

At this point, strictly speaking, you have invoked undefined behaviour because the operation has resulted in overflowing a signed integer.

Answer (score 0):

Let me rewrite the `main` function you wrote - so that it becomes easier to understand.

```
int main()
{
    /*first while loop*/
    int a = 0;
    while (a > 0){ a = a + 1; }

    printf("int max first = %d\n", a-1);

    /*second while loop*/
    int b = 0;
    b = b + 1;
    while (b > 0){ b = b + 1; }

    printf("int max second = %d\n", b-1);

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Some observations regarding what happened here:

1. Because at the beginning of the first while loop - the value of `a` is `0` - which is not greater than `0`; the loop gets skipped at the beginning. As a result, the first `printf` outputs `0`.
2. At the beginning of the second while loop, before evaluating the loop control condition; the loop control variable `b` gets incremented by `1`, resulting the value of `b` becoming `1`; which is greater than `0`. For this reason, the second loop is executed.
3. While executing the second loop, the value of `b` keeps incrementing by `1` until the value of `b` overflows. At this point, the program encounters [*undefined behaviour*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) - and exits the `while` loop if the program doesn't crash or keeps executing the loop indefinitely (in which case, at some stage the OS will terminate the program; or ask the user to terminate it - as the program will become non-responsive).

You mentioned that you wanted to measure the limit of `int` values; I hope [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits) and [this reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) will help you in some way.

Comment: 3: it does not need to crash or exit the loop.

Comment: Of course that is also possible; in that case, the program will become non responsive; making the OS to terminate the program (or ask the user to terminate it).